# JPG not displayed in IE browser

Tags: lightning-aura-components, images, internet-explorer

We have a lightning component to display an image. When the image that is uploaded is jpg, the image is not shown on IE 11. Quick investigation tell us that IE doesn't like src without extension and blocks the rendering in the situation when the format doesn't correspond to what the network indicates. In my case the user upload an jpg image but the mime type is jpeg

```
<img class="{!v.oriantationImage=='portrait' ? 'imd-profile-image imd-pic portrait':'imd-profile-image imd-pic'}"  src="{!ur.MediumPhotoUrl}" alt="user" id="profileImage"/>
```

Question: How we can get the full url with the extension to be displayed in IE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. We implemented like below and its working fine:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <img src="{!$Resource.yourresources}"/>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Which link you added?